# Binding EF to DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm new to EF and struggling with a problem.

I have a WPF app, which contains DataGrid. Let's say it contains list of Products and additional info, so the class looks like

```
class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    }

    public int ProductId (get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Supplier {get; set;}
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Product> products {get; set;}
}
```

Now I wanted to bid this class to grid, so it automatically updates database when someone adds/edit row (or delete with context menu)

So in xaml there is `ItemsSource = "{Binding}"` (writing from memory, excuse small mistakes)
Then I've binded every column to exact property in the class Product.

`OnLoad` method uses database context and goes like this

```
Product product = new Produxt();
Datagrid1.DataContext = ctx.Product.products.ToList();
```

And it shows all the records properly, but then, if I add or edit records, it doesn't affect database :( 
I've read that `ToList` breaks connection with EF, that's why I can't add/edit, but there wasn't any working fix for that. Any ideas?

By the way, where do I put methods for example ShowAllProductsForCustomer(int id)? Do I put them in Products class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple, and if you want, you can bind the data very easily.

Try this:

```
    private void FillData()
    {
        var q = (from a in ctx.Product
                 select a).ToList();
        Datagrid1.ItemsSource = q;
    }
```

I have wrote this off the top of my head, but hopefully you get the gist of what you are trying to do.

Regards,
G.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ctx.Product.products.Load();
//create a bindings source on your form, then use it here
myBindingsSource.DataSource = ctx.Product.products.Local.ToBindingList();
//this can also be done in the properties of the grid on the form
Datagrid1.DataSource = myBindingsSource;
```

I'm doing something similar.
just have to execute the SaveChanges(); method of your context to update the db.